# Encrypting data before uploading to AWS S3 via browser

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk

So I've been working on uploading file to AWS S3 buckets via browser and so far have been able to successfully upload and download files. I'm using **presigned URL** to both upload and download file which I generate through my server. I was wondering as to what will be the best way to encrypt the file data before uploading to S3? Also, how do I decrypt it back on download?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

AWS uses direct upload and download links to avoid data transfer via intermediate servers. If you are adding intermediate encrypt/decrypt in your server it will decrease performance